# Приоритет css файлов

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

Верстал сайт через sass, получился файл style.min.css, залил его на сервер и нужно внести изменения, для этого создаю файл style.css подключаю его после style.min.css и не работает, все перепробовал, подскажите пожалуйста

как сделать style.css более высокий приоритет?

Comment: подключить его раньше style.min.css

Comment: пробовал. 
CMS Bitrix
подключал по API и без API
и перед и после style.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Порядок подключения имеет значение.
Страница считывается слева направо, сверху вниз - предыдущие значения заменяются текущими.

Comment: я это прекрасно понимаю, но я перепробовал все возможные варианты, не помогает..

Comment: а есть возможность опубликовать содержимое тега head?

Comment: получилось =) не понимаю в чем проблема была, скорее всего во мне)